# Python equivalent of Scala's exists() function?

Tags: python, list, scala, exists

Scala lists have an exists() function that returns a boolean if the list has an element that satisfies your predicate.

Is there a way to do this in python that's just as clean?

I've been using

```
if next(x for x in mylist if x > 10): return Something
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 9):

Use [**`any`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any):

```
if any(x > 10 for x in mylist):
    return Something
```

You can complement this with [**`all`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all), and use `not any` and `not all` to round it out.

Your way of using [**`next`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next) will raise an exception if it doesn't find anything. You can pass it an additional default value to return, instead:

```
if next((x for x in mylist if x > 10), None):
    return Something
```