# Extract keywords from a list then use `and`

Tags: python

Well I don't know how to explain this. For example I have the following code:

```
if 'foo' and 'bar' in 'foobar':
    print('foobar')
```

I want to use some keywords to check the sting, and my question is, now I'm trying to put these keywords in a list like this:

```
keywords = ['foo', 'bar']
```

But how can I use them now? If I use `for` to extract them like this:

```
for i in keywords:
    if i in 'foobar':
        print('foobar')
```

But this will print `foobar` twice.

Comment: Note that `'foo' and 'bar' in 'foobar'` == `('foo') and ('bar' in 'foobar')`.

Comment: @PM2Ring Interesting :) What about `'foo' and 'bar' and 'baz' in 'foobar'`? Does it equal to `('foo') and ('bar') and ('baz' in 'foobar')`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a generator expression to loop over all the keywords and check if they are all contained in `'foobar'`. Using `all` will also allow it to short-circuit upon finding the first `False`.

```
if all(i in 'foobar' for i in keywords):
    print('foobar')
```

The analog to this is if you want to `print` if any of the keywords are found, you can use

```
if any(i in 'foobar' for i in keywords):
    print('foobar')
```

Comment: I wonder if you aren't doing this backwards. IE, if keywords is just `['foo']`, it'll print out foobar. I can't quite tell from your question though - do you want to ensure that every keyword is in `'foobar'`, or that every part of `'foobar'` is in the keywords?

Comment: I'm not sure `analog` is the correct term. It's not `opposite` either. The [other day](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33048555/python-equivalent-of-scalas-exists-function/33048617#33048617) I used `complement`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to stick with a loop, you could use a `for-else`.

```
for i in keywords:
    if i not in 'foobar':
        break
else:
    print('foobar')
```

If any `i` is not in `'foobar'`, the loop will exit and skip over the `else` section. The `else` if a `for-else` is only entered if the loop exits without `break`ing, which in this case will only happen if every `i` is in `'foobar'`.